# How to write an interface for a complex http client like gorequest with methods that returns itself for chaining

Tags: go, gorequest

I'm writing a package which needs to pass an instance of a `*gorequest.SuperAgent` to a method in a subpackage

```
// main.go
func main() {
  req := gorequest.New()
  result := subpackage.Method(req)
  fmt.Println(result)
}

// subpackage.go
func Method(req *gorequest.SuperAgent) string {
  req.Get("http://www.foo.com").Set("bar", "baz")
  _, body, _ := req.End()
  return body
}
```

I keep going in circles trying to write an interface for the gorequest superagent so I can properly isolate and test my subpackage methods with a stub of `gorequest`.

```
type Getter Interface {
  Get(url string) Getter
  // In the previous Method, Get() returns a *gorequest.SuperAgent
  // which allows chaining of methods
  // Here I tried returning the interface itself
  // But I get a 'wrong type for Get method' error when passing a gorequest instance
  // have Get(string) *gorequest.SuperAgent
  // want Get(string) Getter

  End(callback ...func(response *gorequest.Response, body string, errs []error)) (*gorequest.Response, string, []error)
  // I have no idea how to handle the param and returned *gorequest.Response here
  // Put another interface ?
  // Tried replacing it with *http.Response but not quite understanding it
}

func Method(req Getter) string {
  ...
}
```

So as you can see I'm tripping up on several points here and haven't been able to find a good source to learn from. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You can't just use an interfere here. For example, `Method() *SuperAgent` isn't `Method() Getter`, they are different signatures.

Comment: @JimB any ideas on how do I isolate `Method()`  then?

Comment: Unfortunately you can't even insert a mocked `http.RoundTripper`, because the SuperAgent is tied directly to an `*http.Transport` struct. If you can recreate the endpoints, you could use an `httptest.Server` and actually make the requests. Otherwise you just have to separate your functionality into testable chunks that can be verified separately from the `SuperAgent` calls. (Personally I wouldn't use `gorequest`.)

Comment: i guess `httptest.Server` is the only way to go then. Feels wrong on a method test but it should do for now. Thanks @JimB. anything beside `gorequest` you would reccomend for my use case ?

Comment: I would use the `net/http` package. Is the `gorequest` really saving you from implementing _that_ much code? Note that saving newline characters by chaining methods doesn't count as saving code, it just formats it differently.

Comment: I was under the impression `net/http` is more low level. Didn't want to get too down and dirty as I'm still pretty fresh in Go. Will look it up @JimB. cheers

Answer (score 1):

Besides defining the `Getter` interface you can also define a thin wrapper around `*gorequest.SuperAgent` that implements the `Getter` interface.

```
type saGetter struct {
    sa *gorequest.SuperAgent
}

func (g *saGetter) Get(url string) Getter {
    g.sa = g.sa.Get(url)
    return g
}

func (g *saGetter) Set(param string, value string) Getter {
    g.sa = g.sa.Set(param, value)
    return g
}

func (g *saGetter) End(callback ...func(response *gorequest.Response, body string, errs []error)) (*gorequest.Response, string, []error) {
    return g.sa.End(callback...)
}
```

Then with your `Method` defined as:

```
// subpackage.go
func Method(req Getter) string {
    req.Get("http://www.foo.com").Set("bar", "baz")
    _, body, _ := req.End()
    return body
}
```

You can use the `saGetter` in main like so:

```
// main.go
func main() {
    req := gorequest.New()
    result := subpackage.Method(&saGetter{req})
    fmt.Println(result)
}
```

Then mocking `Getter` for testing the `Method` implementation is easy.

That said, I agree with @JimB's comments that you probably don't need `gorequest` and using `net/http` is generally the better choice.